# A formula for integral on Implicit surface

Tags: calculus, analysis, vector-analysis

If $S\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ is a surface (2-submanifold) described implicitly as $F(x,y,z)=0$ for $(x,y)\in D$, then $\int_S |F_z|d\sigma=\int_D\sqrt{F_x^2+F_y^2+F_z^2}dxdy$.

I can prove this in the case that $F(x,y,z)=0\iff z=G(x,y)$ for some function $G$. But this can't work in the case that $S$ is the unit sphere. Is there an easy way to find a proof? Apologize for possible mistakes.

Comment: Your counterexample doesn't work - if $S$ is the unit sphere the quantity on the left evaluates to $4\pi$ but the quantity on the right is $2\pi$. In order for the condition $(x,y)\in D$ to make any sense, $z$ must be $G(x,y)$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks! I think the proof is complete now.